# Validate base64 encoded image from mime byte

Tags: php, security, image-processing, encoding, base64

I'm trying to validate some Base64 encoded images from the mime type byte, they are all validating correctly except for .png files

The png byte signature is **89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A**

I have an array of allowed byte signatures

```
    'imageBytes'    => [
        "jpeg"  => "FFD8",
        "png"   => "89504E470D0A1A0A",
        "gif"   => "474946",
        "bmp"   => "424D"
    ],
```

I pass a base64 encoded image to this function with my allowed array

```
    public function checkImageMimeBytes(string $imageData, array $imgByteArray) : string
        {
            if (!is_array($imgByteArray) || is_null($imgByteArray) || empty($imgByteArray)) {
                throw new \LogicException('undefined image security config');
            }

            foreach ($imgByteArray as $mime => $hexBytes) {
                $bytes = $this->getBytesFromHexString($hexBytes);
                if (substr($imageData, 0, strlen($bytes)) == $bytes) {
                    return $mime;
                } else {
                    throw new SecurityException;
                }
            }
            throw new \LogicException('Invalid Mime Byte');
        }
```

this function gets the bytes from hex string

```
        public function getBytesFromHexString(string $hexData) : string
        {

            for ($count = 0; $count < strlen($hexData); $count += 2) {
                $bytes[] = chr(hexdec(substr($hexData, $count, 2)));
            }

            if (!isset($bytes) || !is_array($bytes) || empty($bytes) || is_null($bytes)) {
                throw new \LogicException;
            }

            return implode($bytes);
        }
```

When testing it always throws a security exception for .png images

Any info on how to fix this?

[image: edit test image]

added test image

edit:
encoding front end from javascript with FileReader()

```
     let reader = new FileReader()
     reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        reader.onloadend = (readEvent) => {
          this.$emit('imageUploadReady', readEvent.currentTarget.result)
        }
```

Comment: We don't know what your data looks like.

Comment: Have you tried using base64_encode and base64_decode?

Comment: Why would I need to encode it and decode it? I encode it client side with javascript and decode it server side?

Comment: added test image

Comment: The image doesn't help. Show the data.

Comment: base64 https://jsfiddle.net/3zzz567s/

Comment: decoded
https://jsfiddle.net/3zzz567s/1/

Comment: Your magic numbers are to strict anyway, these will fail for a variety of different images, even if they are the same format.

Comment: @Trickycm what would you suggest then?

Comment: Sorry, that was a little short. Google magic numbers for image types and add more choices per type. You may also consider only using the first 4 bytes.

Comment: I have googled and can only find 1 file signature for .png which the one giving me issues

https://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?search=png&mode=EXT
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

Just like you, I have a base64 image (`$imageBase64Str`).

I need to get the mime type of this image which must be valid.

## Answer

Input: `$imageBase64Str`

```php
function imgMime($imgBytes){
    if(is_null($imgBytes)){
        return(false);
    }
    if(strlen($imgBytes)<12){
        return(false);
    }
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime=$finfo->buffer($imgBytes);
    if(strncmp($mime, "image/", 6) != 0){
        return(false);
    }
    return($mime);
}

$imageBytes=base64_decode($imageBase64Str,true);
if(!$imageBytes){
    throw new Exception("cannot decode image base64");
}
$imageMime=imgMime($imageBytes);
if(!$imageMime){
    throw new Exception("cannot recognize image mime");
}
```

If you wish to limit the image types to a narrower set of mimes than what the `exif_imagetype` function recognizes, you can throw an error based on the `$imageMime` returned by the [image_type_to_mime_type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php) function. Something like this:

```php
$allowedMimes=["image/jpeg","image/png","image/gif","image/bmp"];
if(!in_array($imageMime,$allowedMimes,true)){
    throw new Exception("image mime not allowed: ".$imageMime);
}
```

## Outcome

When I set `$imageBase64Str` to `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQwAAABuCAYAAADSxy12AAAgAElEQVR4XtV9267jSpJd8CaSukvVv+LpA...Vxt5tFRObQnEEvPk4fVOUFg5tz2709kx8kLz9c0yWJqDQQqfvvSxPV0wVSYRMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=` extracted from [your example](https://jsfiddle.net/3zzz567s/), I get a valid `image/png` mime. However, I don't get the cool black and white anonymous minion cowboy image but the following violet/purple rotated squares below:

[image: resulting png image]